# how can i get one value to another on user click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two text box
when i press a button text of textbox one can automatically display on textbox2.
i used V S 2010
I need this code in c#

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to get their homework done for them. ;)

Comment: maybe some javascript...

Comment: if you do it in WPF using binding, you don't even need a button.

Comment: i dont kno a abc of c# there for give me best referenc for study it....on a internet

Comment: Honestly it's best to buy a book, but I guess you could check out MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the button click event write this line:

```
textbox2.Text = textbox.Text;
```

PS. try to read a book like C# for dummies

Answer (score 3):

In the button's click event:

`Textbox2.Text = Textbox1.Text`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value to change as you are typing it, check out the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event

```
textbox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPressedEvent);

private void KeyPressedEvent(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: @Gulu - You and assign that in the designer.  Just click on the textbox1 and select the lightnigh bolt on the Properties page.  Then scroll down until you see `KeyPress` and enter in `KeyPressedEvent`.  That will add it to the designer.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

```
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb1.Top = 100;
        tb2.Top = 100 + tb1.Height;
        tb1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb1_TextChanged);
        this.Controls.Add(tb1);
        this.Controls.Add(tb2);
    }


    void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb2.Text = tb1.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using codebehind such as `TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;` and without a button. You can do it all in XAML with a single property in your C# code.

your C# code (A.K.A. the ViewModel)

```
private string _textBoxContent;
public string TextBoxContent
{
    get { return _textBoxContent; }
    set
    {
        _textBoxContent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxContent");
    }
}
```

and your XAML will look like this:

```
<TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding TextBoxContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Name="tb2"  Text="{Binding TextBoxContent, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This will cause changes to tb1 to show in tb2 as you type in tb1. However, it will not change the value of tb1 as you type in tb2.

To have tb1 and tb2 both update each other's value, just use the same binding statement from tb1.

Comment: if you don't add the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the binding statement, you must exit the textbox before it will update the value of the other textbox.